# Installation problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

HI guys I have an annoying problem. I wanted to replace windows with Ubuntu on my labtop. I used my USB to install ubuntu successfully but now when I reboot it without the USB it says no boot able device or something like that. I used the boot repair software to try to fix it but it didn't work. http://paste2.org/pn7mxkj7 is the url I was told to write down to help me fix it. Can someone please help me

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l
NAME         MOUNTPOINT                                LABEL        SIZE FSTYPE
sda                                                                29.6G 
└─sda1       /cdrom                                    UBUNTU 16_0 29.6G vfat
loop0        /rofs                                                  1.4G squashf
mmcblk0rpmb                                                           4M 
mmcblk0boot0                                                          4M 
mmcblk0boot1                                                          4M 
mmcblk0                                                            29.1G 
├─mmcblk0p1                                                         512M vfat
├─mmcblk0p2  /media/ubuntu/1cbc9f59-3734-4d9c-92f2-177             26.7G ext4
└─mmcblk0p3                                                         1.9G swap
Model: PNY USB 3.0 FD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 31.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  31.7GB  31.7GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Error: /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: unrecognised disk label
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore?
```

Comment: Which software did you use to create a bootable drive, rufus ? Are you sure the image file you downloaded is not corrupt ? Did you try using a different USB ?

Comment: I installed everything correctly. My

Comment: I think I used rufus. I installed Ubuntu and it works but when I reboot it with the USB stick it goes to the gnu grub version 2.02 with options to * Try Ubuntu without installing,install ubuntu,OEM install (for manufacturers),or check disc for defects. And when I reboot with the USB stick it has a black screen that says no bootable device in the middle of the screen and stays there.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam The usb isn't installation media isn't the problem.  His question shows that he successfully installed the OS.  When he installed the OS he mistakenly specified the installation medium as his boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently installed Grub on the USB stick during the install, not the `/dev/sda`.  You can fix this by installing grub on `/dev/sda`.

Perform the steps provided here for a different question, but the same resolution (the details of all the steps are in the link)  Click on the link:

Dual Boot don't work on Windows 10:
https://askubuntu.com/a/831175/29012

Perform these steps at the terminal command prompt after booting into the Live media:

Replace `/dev/sdaX` with the partition where Ubuntu is installed.
Replace `/dev/sdX` with the drive in your computer which is `/dev/sda`.

The "**$**" symbol is the terminal prompt you see where you type the command.  The "**$**" prompt is a normal user.  The "**#**" prompt is when running as `root`.  The prompt will change while performing the steps.  Copy and paste the command that appears after the prompt.  The prompts are showing that the lines are terminal commands.

```bash
$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt  
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

```
# update-grub  
# exit
```

```bash
$ sudo for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo umount "/mnt/$i"; done  
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ exit
```

Now `reboot` the computer and you'll be all set without the USB device.

Comment: the guy joined askubuntu today and is trying to install ubuntu in his computer. Please, give a simple solution. Even, I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: Did you go to the link with the details?  Just because a person is new to Ubuntu or new to SE doesn't make them completely illiterate.  He appears to understand `links`.  Can you specify which part of the steps in the link is confusing to you?  I'll fix the details in the `link` if they don't work.  It was my intentions to get a perfect description in a link link  for this recurring problem... making the link extremely easy to follow and pointing to it for all the variations of having a failed boot.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam By the way, the brief steps and the referred link is intended to be legible to people who haven' t joined AS yet, but grabbed an ISO and had a failed boot.  Thanks in advance if you would point out any confusion or discrepancies in the link that might not work or might not be able to be followed by a novice.

Comment: I am sorry if I offended you. I didn't have any such intentions. I also don't have any idea on "links". Therefore,  I couldn't understand your answer.

Comment: I'm not offended.  I'm glad to explain any component of my description and to know which parts are confusing so that I can clarify and become better at explaining.  This is a "Link" : "http://askubuntu.com/a/831175/29012" .  Also this is a "link": [link to details](http://askubuntu.com/a/831175/29012).   I'll fix the `link` in the answer to try to be clearer what it's linked to.  Thanks for the feeedback and input.

Comment: I know what a `"Link" is. The way you laid emphasis and highlighted it made me think it's something else. I guess we should delete all these comments as these are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: When I type sudo mount /dev/sda it says "mount:can't find /dev/sda in /etc/fstab

Comment: Hey,I don't know if this matters but I have a aspire one cloud book 14 and it has a 32 gb harddrive. I just showed a friend and he said my hard drive is too small. I hope he is wrong.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks for testing the commands.  There was a problem in the way the command was written.  I have checked it and verified.  the `/mnt` was left out, but is now fixed.  Run the commands the way they are now and your issue will be resolved.  Please advise if you get an error anywhere.  It should only take about 5 minutes to have the issue resolved.  Let us know the results.

Comment: Where do I add the /mnt?

Comment: @L.D. James I dont inderstand your instructions where it says replace dev/sdaX with the partition where Ubuntu is installed. I don't know what my partition is that Ubuntu is installed

Comment: @Jeffrey What is the size of your hard drive?  Will you run this command exactly in the terminal and paste the results to your message: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`

Comment: The command I just gave you will show which partition has your Ubuntu installed.

Comment: NAME         MOUNTPOINT                                LABEL        SIZE FSTYPE
sda                                                                29.6G 
└─sda1       /cdrom                                    UBUNTU 16_0 29.6G vfat
loop0        /rofs                                                  1.4G squashf
mmcblk0rpmb                                                           4M

Comment: mmcblk0boot0                                                          4M 
mmcblk0boot1                                                          4M 
mmcblk0                                                            29.1G 
├─mmcblk0p1                                                         512M vfat
├─mmcblk0p2  /media/ubuntu/1cbc9f59-3734-4d9c-92f2-177             26.7G ext4
└─mmcblk0p3                                                         1.9G swap
parted: invalid option -- '1'
Usage: parted [-hlmsv] [-a<align>] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...]

Comment: @Jeffrey Small amount of space available for comments are not allowing me to see the output of the command.  You'll have to use the `edit` command in your question and add the output to  your question

Comment: @L.D.James itried copying and pasting it and it still comes out messed up. i also tried typing it and also same problem

Comment: @Jeffrey You copied and pasted it.  Give me a second to look at what you put.

Comment: @Jeffrey Actually the problem now is that you typed it instead of coping and pasting the information.  Please perform this command exact. `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l` then copy and paste the content to your question.  I can probably see what I need from what you typed.  But I'll need you to actually paste the full content for me to be sure.  Thanks!  By the way, don't worry about how it looks to you... just make sure it's the full content.  As long as you paste the full content I can format the output.

Comment: i just copied and pasted it right now

Comment: The problem now is that you used the number `-1` instead of the letter `-l` that is in the command.  Can you try it again.  It would work much better to copy and paste the command to get it right.  I'll need the full output.  The only problem this time was missing the `-l`.  The exact command is: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`

Comment: @Jeffrey it looks like, for the output so far that you may only have a 30gig hard drive in your computer.  The output of this command will shed a lot of light on the subject.  I asked what is the size of your hard drive.  Also, we need the output so that I can tell you exactly how to replace the `X` in the fix above.  The exact command is `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`.  If it's input exact there won't be any errors.  Do the command as best as you can and I'll figure out the errors and what is going wrong.

Comment: @L.D.James i justed tried it again. and by the way i have a 32 GB hardrive. i hope this time i got it right

Comment: @Jeffrey Looking at your output, you don't have Ubuntu installed on your hard drive... the 32 GB harddrive you have in your computer.  Perform the install steps you said you did the last time.  Use the option that refers to erase the drive and replace it with Ubuntu.  Choose `/dev/sda` for your boot partition during the install process.

Comment: @L.D.James I tried installing it again and I still have the same proble.. when I try to install it in the something  else option I notice that my free space is 1MB. And I saw on a YouTube video that that is where I have to install my ubuntu. So I guess I don't have enough memory. How do I make the free space larger so that I can inot all it?

Comment: @Jeffrey Are you trying to keep something on preserve anything on the hard drive?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46519/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-installation-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04).